# WP_LIST_PAGES custom output using WP_QUERY

Tags: wordpress, customization

I need to display all children and grandchildren of a parent page, but I want a custom output instead of the standard one given by wp_list_pages();

```
<?php
    wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li'    => '',
        'child_of' => $post->ID
    ));
?>
```

I managed to display down to children page, but no grandchildren using this:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <span></span>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions on how to extend this code to show grandchildren under child pages just like the original wp_list_pages()?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a nice way to extend wp_list_pages();

```
<?php
    wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'link_before' => '<span></span><h3>',
        'link_after' => '</h3>'
    ));
?>
```

Is not exactly what I wanted, like to customize the list and add some extra things, but this will work just fine for what I need.